# How do you download metadata for TCGA pathology slides

Tags: genome

I downloaded the TCGA pathology slides for the SKCM project and the files are all a name such as "TCGA-3N-A9WB-01Z-00-DX1.A9950ED4-9480-455C-AE0D-8E076D4DA432.svs".
How do you get the clinical metadata for this dataset? When I click "clinical" for the project, the .tsv file has no case IDs that match to my file names.

https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/exploration?filters=%7B%22content%22%3A%5B%7B%22content%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22cases.case_id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%22set_id%3AYavV3YoBvzAafV-N5zuW%22%5D%7D%2C%22op%22%3A%22IN%22%7D%5D%2C%22op%22%3A%22AND%22%7D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The patient ID is the first 10 letters, e.g. "TCGA-3N-A9WB-01Z-00-DX1.A9950ED4-9480-455C-AE0D-8E076D4DA432.svs" relates to the patient "TCGA-3N-A9WB". If you download the clinical information for SKCM, there is clinical info in the tsv for patient "TCGA-3N-A9WB". Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!